# How to properly putting enumerate inside a defined environment?

Tags: environments, enumerate

I'm using an environment to work with a form-type of information, I'm trying to use enumerate for automatic numbering. Here's my current output :

[image]

And here's my code,

```
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tabforms}
    \tabform{a.}{Course name}{:}{History of Art}
    \tabform{b.}{Credits}{:}{4 (four)}
    \tabform{c.}{Lecturer}{:}{Raisa Andriana}
    \tabform{d.}{Room}{:}{Main hall Apolo, building A}
 \end{tabforms}
 \end{document}
```

As you can see, I'm defining my alphabet numbering manually. It works exactly as I want, however the information add-ups a lot & sometimes I lost track of the alphabets and had to re-order them from the beginning, that's why I'm trying to use enumerate. Here's my environment :

```
\newenvironment{tabforms}{%
  \begin{longtable}{
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.1cm}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4.5cm}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.1cm}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{12cm}  %%% \\ 
        }}{ \end{longtable} \vspace{-1mm}
}
\newcommand\tabform[4]{%
#1 & #2 & #3 & #4  \\ }
```

I'm trying to implement enumerate on my code using this :

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
\item 
\item 
\end{enumerate}
```

Which worked perfectly outside an environment. I tried to implement it inside my environment with no luck, this is what I have tried (manual numbering is still there because I just wanted to know if it worked or not) :

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tabforms}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
        \item \tabform{a.}{Course name}{:}{History of Art}
        \item \tabform{b.}{Credits}{:}{4 (four)}
        \item \tabform{c.}{Lecturer}{:}{Raisa Andriana}
        \item \tabform{d.}{Room}{:}{Main hall Apolo, building A}
\end{enumerate}
\end{tabforms}
\end{document}
```

It didn't work, I encounter these errors in each item line :

```
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup
Missing \endgroup inserted
Missing } inserted
Overfull ...
```

Is it possible to implement enumerate in this case ? and how do I properly put it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to use `itemize`. Instead, what you want to do is create your own counter. We'll assume that you're not going to have nested `tabforms` environments (if that's not the case, that will be a bit more involved.

You'll need to create a new counter for your `\tabform` command, let's call it `tabform`:

```
\newcounter{tabform}
```

Next we want to be able to use it in the environment. We'll want it to print as a lowercase letter and the formatting is determined by the `\thetabform` command which we can redefine as

```
\renewcommand{\thetabform}{\alph{tabform}}
```

(There are also commands `\arabic`, `\Alph`, `\roman` and `\Roman` that you could have used.)

Now we want to print the number as part of `\tabform` which will look like this:

```
\newcommand\tabform[3]{%
  \refstepcounter{tabform}\thetabform. & #1 & #2 & #3   \\ }
```

What we did was to replace the first argument in your long table with the command to print the counter after incrementing its value. Using `\refstepcounter` allows us to use `\label` and `\ref` for cross-referencing.

Finally, we want to make sure that if we have more than one `tabforms` environment in the document that each one starts with “a.” We do this by setting the `tabform` counter to 0 as part of the `\begin` environment definition:

```
\newenvironment{tabforms}{%
  \setcounter{tabform}{0}%
  \begin{longtable}{
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.1cm}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4.5cm}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.1cm}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{12cm}  %%% \\ 
        }}{ \end{longtable} \vspace{-1mm}
}
```

Comment: And to forestall a predictable comment, yes, there is `\fnsymbol` for printing the value of a counter as one of a series of footnote symbols, but it's unlikely to be used in this context.

Comment: It works, thank you. Also your explanation is very detailed and easy to understand, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the commands you have already defined, I think that using an `enumerate` environment is not the easiest way to make the numbering automatic. Instead, you could define a new counter, and increment it at each new call of `\tabform` to number the corresponding row.

Here's an example I built from yours. I added a new `tabcount` counter which is reset at the beginning of a `tabforms` environment. I modified `\tabform` to make the first argument optional. If it is given it will be placed in the table as in your first example, but if it is not given then `tabcount` will be incremented and used to number the row automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcounter{tabcount}
\renewcommand{\thetabcount}{\alph{tabcount}.}

\newenvironment{tabforms}{%
    \setcounter{tabcount}{0}
    \begin{longtable}{
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.1cm}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4.5cm}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.1cm}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{12cm}
        }}{ \end{longtable} \vspace{-1mm}
}
\newcommand\tabform[4][]{%
    \def\temp{#1}%
    \ifx\temp\empty
        \refstepcounter{tabcount}%
        \thetabcount%
    \else
        \temp%
    \fi%
    & #2 & #3 & #4 \\ %
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabforms}
    \tabform{Course name}{:}{History of Art}
    \tabform{Credits}{:}{4 (four)}
    \tabform{Lecturer}{:}{Raisa Andriana}
    \tabform{Room}{:}{Main hall Apolo, building A}
 \end{tabforms}
 \end{document}
```

The above example yields the expected output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Defining a new counter works. Someone else posted an answer with the same approach, literally just 30 seconds faster so I accepted his answer.